# capturing all wpf controls in a foreach statement

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF program made of rectangle controls with different tags and image sources as a fill and I want to do a foreach on all my controlls to do different logic based on their tags.

```
foreach (Rectangle o in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(program))
                {
                    if (o is Rectangle && o.Tag.ToString() == "platform" ){}
```

however I get an error say "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Image' to type 'System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle'." Am I using the wrong Rectangle reference?

Comment: I would just change to `foreach(var o ....`, to make my life easier.
Note that you are only searching the first level children, did you make sure the `Rectangle` you are looking for is at the first level?

Answer (score 0):

Its saying that not all children are `Rectangle` (and you seem to have the wrong one as well, you want the control not the shape).

Just filter down to the rectangles:

```
foreach (Rectangle o in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(program).OfType<Rectangle>())
```

Comment: to use the control not the shape rectangle how do I differentiate? just use the full namespace?

Comment: @wintersummer or remove the `using System.Drawing.Shapes` from the top and add a using for the controls

Comment: tried that got its only recognizing rectangle as a shapes class and not finding a type for rectangle. weird.

Comment: maybe im not using a controls class? that wouldn't make sense though since I added them all through the xaml

Comment: @wintersummer that is certainly possible though I thought there was a control there

Comment: its not registering like I would hope. I tried with (foreach control  o in logical tree) and changing the rectangle to image if (o is image) and its saying the given expression is never of type image so I dont think im capturing it correctly in my foreach.... suggestings?

Comment: I don't recall if `GetChildren` is recursive; if its not you may only be getting top level children. FWIW this is a very off use case; you may just have a giant XY problem here.